Get data from public-pool running on Umbrel
I am running my own public-pool instance on my Umbrel node (https://apps.umbrel.com/app/public-pool) mining using a Bitaxe device. For sport. Not for profit.
As I can access my node via VPN (https://apps.umbrel.com/app/tailscale), I'd like to access the mining info (hash rate, best difficulty) remotely, via curl. I thought I could curl the public-pool backend or parse the html page to get the data, but when try to curl (or wget) the URL, I get the Umbrel password page.
Does anyone have a better idea or an alternative for public-pool?

Have you given up on accessing Public Pool via Umbrel?
I've just connected to PP on a similar setup as yours:

Full Node on Tor-enabled Umbrel via dedicated RP5
Bitaxe Supra

FROM TOR BROWSER

Open Tor browser --> Connect.
Enter Node's Tor link
Establish connection to Umbrel

FROM UMBREL.

Umbrel Login --> enter PW
Open Bitcoin Core (select "load normally")
Open Public-Pool (select "load normally")
Re-enter Umbrel login PW

If all goes well, should be taken to your node's public pool dashboard.
